# How to animate a dynamically changing div when a button is clicked

Tags: css, animation, transition

A snippet of code for a portfolio showing projects using specified languages. The returning divs INSTANTLY change but I want an animation effect when they are changed.  Heres my HTML:

```
                <div>
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" onclick="checkProjects('python');">Python</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" onclick="checkProjects('javascript');">Javascript</button>

                </div>

            <div class="col s6 project-list">
                <div class = "project1 col s12">
                    <div id="project1Title" class="project-title col s12"></div>
                    <img id="project1Pic" class="project-picture col s6" src="">
                    <div id ="project1Caption" class="col s6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="project2 col s12">
                    <div id="project2Title" class="project-title col s12"></div>
                    <img id="project2Pic" class="project-picture col s6" src="">
                    <div id ="project2Caption" class="project-caption col s6"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I would like an animation everytime project1...project2...etc is changed.

Comment: Try using animate.css ? https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: What do you mean by "when they are changed"? What is changing?

Comment: Is a user clicking it to reveal more info? Are they navigating a slideshow of the projects?

Comment: The div changes and shows a projects title/picture/caption.  They are clicking to see which projects use python, javascript, etc

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two basic ways I can think of to accomplish what you're trying to do.

You can either

1. Add / remove a class to transition to whatever styles you want.
2. Manually animate the transition using javascript or jquery.

It sounds like your animation is more complex, and it may be best to use jquery.

```
// When the user clicks on a project
$('.project').on('click',function() {

  // Animate the project element
  $(this).animate({
    opacity:1
  },{duration:200,queue:false})

  // To access this specific project's child 
  // elements (ie, title, picture, caption) you will 
  // need to use .children
  $(this).children('.project-title').animate({
    opacity:1,
    top:'50px'
  },{duration:200,queue:false})
})
```

Jquery's animation functionality can be very useful for complex, multi-element animations, check [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more info

Comment: Also, it looks like your caption and title divs are empty. You could also place content in those in this function via `$('project-title').innerHTML('content')`. 
But it would probably be best to place the content in the markup, then hide/reveal them with jquery.

Comment: The divs are not hard-coded because they change via the checkProjects() function when the buttons are clicked